# Missionaries and cannibals problem In C++

Tags: c++, bgi

I've been searching for Missionaries and cannibals problem solving.
After lots of searching, I finally reached the code below, but it shows some errors while compiling.

I changed `#include <iostream.h>` to `#include<iostream>` and added `using namespace std;`
but it still shows some error while compiling:

> [Error] '::main' must return 'int'
>   In function 'int main()'
>   [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>   [Error] name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]
>   [Note] (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<dos.h>
     void rectangel(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
       {
    line(x1,y1,x2,y1);
    line(x1,y1,x1,y2);
    line(x1,y2,x2,y2);
    line(x2,y1,x2,y2);
       }
   struct node{
        int state[3];
        int action[2];
        int depth;
        int veiw;
                  }root;
  struct node empty={    0,0,0,
             0,0,
             0,
             0
                };

  struct node stack[50];
  int top=0;
  void clear()
  {
   for(int j=0;j<=50;j++)
   stack[top]=empty;
  }
  void push(struct node t)
  {
   stack[top]=t;
   top++;
  }
  struct node pop()
  {
    top--;
    return stack[top];
    }
  int emptyf()
  {
   if(top==0)
   return 1;
   else return 0;
  }
  void succesor(struct node n)
  {
   struct node k;
   if(n.state[2]==1)
   {
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0]-1;
    k.state[1]=n.state[1];
    k.state[2]=0;
    k.action[0]=-1;
    k.action[1]=0;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0]-2;
    k.state[1]=n.state[1];
    k.state[2]=0;
    k.action[0]=-2;
    k.action[1]=0;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0];
    k.state[1]=n.state[1]-1;
    k.state[2]=0;
    k.action[0]=0;
    k.action[1]=-1;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0];
    k.state[1]=n.state[1]-2;
    k.state[2]=0;
    k.action[0]=0;
    k.action[1]=-2;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0]-1;
    k.state[1]=n.state[1]-1;
    k.state[2]=0;
    k.action[0]=-1;
    k.action[1]=-1;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
   }
   if(n.state[2]==0)
   {
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0]+1;
    k.state[1]=n.state[1];
    k.state[2]=1;
    k.action[0]=1;
    k.action[1]=0;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0];
    k.state[1]=n.state[1]+1;
    k.state[2]=1;
    k.action[0]=0;
    k.action[1]=1;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0]+2;
    k.state[1]=n.state[1];
    k.state[2]=1;
    k.action[0]=2;
    k.action[1]=0;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0]+1;
    k.state[1]=n.state[1]+1;
    k.state[2]=1;
    k.action[0]=1;
    k.action[1]=1;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
    k.depth=n.depth+1;
    k.state[0]=n.state[0];
    k.state[1]=n.state[1]+2;
    k.state[2]=1;
    k.action[0]=0;
    k.action[1]=2;
    k.veiw=0;
    push(k);
   }
  }
  int goal=0;
  struct node IDS(int l)
  {
  struct node g;
   while(emptyf()!=1 && goal!=1)
   {
    g=pop();
   if(g.depth!=0 && g.state[0]==3 && g.state[1]==3 && g.state[2]==1)
    continue;
     if ((g.state[0]==0 && g.state[1]==2 && g.state[2]==0) ||
     (g.state[0]==1 && g.state[1]==2 && g.state[2]==0) ||
     (g.state[0]==0 && g.state[1]==1 && g.state[2]==0) ||
     (g.state[0]==1 && g.state[1]==2 && g.state[2]==1))
    continue;
     if(g.state[0]<0 || g.state[1]<0 || g.state[0]>3 || g.state[1]>3)
     continue;
     if(g.state[0]>g.state[1] && g.state[1]!=0)
     continue;
    if(g.state[0]==0 && g.state[1]==0 && g.state[2]==0)
     {
      goal=1;
      struct node mmm=g;
      return mmm;
      }
    if(g.depth<l && g.veiw==0)
     {
      g.veiw=1;
      push(g);
      succesor(g);
     }
   }
   return g;
  }
   void main()
  {
    //clrscr();
       int gdriver = DETECT , gmode , errorcode;
       initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "d:\\tc\\bgi");
       errorcode = graphresult();
       if (errorcode != grOk)
     {
       cout<<"Graphics error: %s\n"<< grapherrormsg(errorcode)<<endl;
       cout<<"Press any key to halt:";
       getch();
       exit(1);
      }
    root.state[0]=3;
    root.state[1]=3;
    root.state[2]=1;
    root.action[0]=0;
    root.action[1]=0;
    root.depth=0;
    root.veiw=0;
    int d=0;
    struct node km;
    while(goal!=1)
    {
      clear();
      push(root);
      km=IDS(d);
      d++;
     }
     int array[40];
     int dd=km.depth;
     int index=0;
     array[index]=km.state[2];
     index++;
     array[index]=km.state[1];
     index++;
     array[index]=km.state[0];
    cout<<"depth="<<d<<endl;
    while(!(km.state[0]==3 && km.state[1]==3 && km.state[2]==1))
    {
     km=pop();
     if(km.depth==dd)
     continue;
     if(km.depth==dd-1)
     {
      index++;
      array[index]=km.state[2];
     index++;
     array[index]=km.state[1];
     index++;
     array[index]=km.state[0];
      dd=km.depth;
       }
    }
    int count=0;
    int tmparay[40];
    for(int i=0;i<index+1;i++)
    tmparay[i]=array[index-i];
      count=0;
       int aray[12][3];
       for(i=0;i<12;i++)
       {
    aray[i][0]=tmparay[count];
    count++;
    aray[i][1]=tmparay[count];
    count++;
    aray[i][2]=tmparay[count];
    count++;
       }
       for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
     cout<<" "<<aray[i][j];
     cout<<endl;
     }
     cout<<"                                            Missionaries"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
     cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
     cout<<"                                            Cannibals";
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      for(i=0;i<12;i++)
       {
     if(aray[i][2]==1)
     {
       if((aray[i][0]==3) && (aray[i][1]==3))
       {
         setcolor(0);
         rectangel(220,280,250,330);
         setcolor(7);
         rectangel(150,200,250,400);
         rectangel(150,280,180,330);
         rectangel(60,210,80,230);
         rectangel(90,210,110,230);
         rectangel(120,210,140,230);
         rectangel(60,370,80,390);
         rectangel(90,370,110,390);
         rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       }
     else if((aray[i][0]==3) && (aray[i][1]==0))
        {
          setcolor(0);
          rectangel(220,280,250,330);
          rectangel(60,210,80,230);
          rectangel(90,210,110,230);
          rectangel(120,210,140,230);
          rectangel(260,370,280,390);
          rectangel(290,370,310,390);
          rectangel(320,370,340,390);
          setcolor(7);
          rectangel(150,200,250,400);
          rectangel(150,280,180,330);
          rectangel(60,370,80,390);
          rectangel(90,370,110,390);
          rectangel(120,370,140,390);
          rectangel(260,210,280,230);
          rectangel(290,210,310,230);
          rectangel(320,210,340,230);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==2) && (aray[i][1]==3))
     {
      setcolor(0);
      rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      rectangel(120,370,140,390);
      rectangel(260,210,280,230);
      rectangel(290,210,310,230);
      rectangel(320,210,340,230);
      rectangel(290,370,310,390);
      rectangel(320,370,340,390);
      setcolor(7);
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      rectangel(150,280,180,330);
      rectangel(60,210,80,230);
      rectangel(90,210,110,230);
      rectangel(120,210,140,230);
      rectangel(60,370,80,390);
      rectangel(90,370,110,390);
      rectangel(260,370,280,390);
      }
     else if((aray[i][0]==2) && (aray[i][1]==2))
     {
      setcolor(0);
      rectangel(290,370,310,390);
      rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      rectangel(320,370,340,390);
      rectangel(290,210,310,230);
      rectangel(320,210,340,230);
      rectangel(120,370,140,390);
      rectangel(120,210,140,230);
      setcolor(7);
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      rectangel(150,280,180,330);
      rectangel(60,210,80,230);
      rectangel(90,210,110,230);
      rectangel(60,370,80,390);
      rectangel(90,370,110,390);
      rectangel(260,210,280,230);
      rectangel(260,370,280,390);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==2) && (aray[i][1]==0))
     {
       setcolor(0);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
       rectangel(320,370,340,390);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
       rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       rectangel(60,210,80,230);
       rectangel(90,210,110,230);
       rectangel(120,210,140,230);
       setcolor(7);
       rectangel(150,200,250,400);
       rectangel(150,280,180,330);
       rectangel(60,370,80,390);
       rectangel(90,370,110,390);
       rectangel(260,210,280,230);
       rectangel(290,210,310,230);
       rectangel(320,210,340,230);
       rectangel(260,370,280,390);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==1) && (aray[i][1]==3))
     {
       setcolor(0);
       rectangel(90,370,110,390);
       rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       rectangel(220,280,250,330);
       rectangel(260,210,280,230);
       rectangel(290,210,310,230);
       rectangel(320,210,340,230);
       rectangel(320,370,340,390);
       setcolor(7);
       rectangel(150,200,250,400);
       rectangel(60,210,80,230);
       rectangel(90,210,110,230);
       rectangel(120,210,140,230);
       rectangel(60,370,80,390);
       rectangel(150,280,180,330);
       rectangel(260,370,280,390);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
      }
     else if((aray[i][0]==1) && (aray[i][1]==1))
     {
       setcolor(0);
       rectangel(260,210,280,230);
       rectangel(260,370,280,390);
       rectangel(90,370,110,390);
       rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       rectangel(220,280,250,330);
       rectangel(90,210,110,230);
       rectangel(120,210,140,230);
       setcolor(7);
       rectangel(150,200,250,400);
       rectangel(150,280,180,330);
       rectangel(60,210,80,230);
       rectangel(60,370,80,390);
       rectangel(290,210,310,230);
       rectangel(320,210,340,230);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
       rectangel(320,370,340,390);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==1) && (aray[i][1]==0))
      {
      setcolor(0);
      rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      rectangel(320,370,340,390);
      rectangel(60,210,80,230);
      rectangel(90,210,110,230);
      rectangel(120,210,140,230);
      rectangel(90,370,110,390);
      rectangel(120,370,140,390);
      setcolor(7);
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      rectangel(60,370,80,390);
      rectangel(150,280,180,330);
      rectangel(260,210,280,230);
      rectangel(290,210,310,230);
      rectangel(320,210,340,230);
      rectangel(260,370,280,390);
      rectangel(290,370,310,390);
     }
     }
       if(aray[i][2]==0)
     {
       if((aray[i][0]==3) && (aray[i][1]==3))
       {
         setcolor(0);
         rectangel(150,280,180,330);
         setcolor(7);
         rectangel(150,200,250,400);
         rectangel(220,280,250,330);
         rectangel(60,210,80,230);
         rectangel(90,210,110,230);
         rectangel(120,210,140,230);
         rectangel(60,370,80,390);
         rectangel(90,370,110,390);
         rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       }
     else if((aray[i][0]==3) && (aray[i][1]==0))
        {
          setcolor(0);
          rectangel(150,280,180,330);
          rectangel(60,210,80,230);
          rectangel(90,210,110,230);
          rectangel(120,210,140,230);
          rectangel(260,370,280,390);
          rectangel(290,370,310,390);
          rectangel(320,370,340,390);
          setcolor(7);
          rectangel(150,200,250,400);
          rectangel(220,280,250,330);
          rectangel(60,370,80,390);
          rectangel(90,370,110,390);
          rectangel(120,370,140,390);
          rectangel(260,210,280,230);
          rectangel(290,210,310,230);
          rectangel(320,210,340,230);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==2) && (aray[i][1]==3))
     {
      setcolor(0);
      rectangel(150,280,180,330);
      rectangel(120,370,140,390);
      rectangel(260,210,280,230);
      rectangel(290,210,310,230);
      rectangel(320,210,340,230);
      rectangel(290,370,310,390);
      rectangel(320,370,340,390);
      setcolor(7);
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      rectangel(60,210,80,230);
      rectangel(90,210,110,230);
      rectangel(120,210,140,230);
      rectangel(60,370,80,390);
      rectangel(90,370,110,390);
      rectangel(260,370,280,390);
      }
     else if((aray[i][0]==2) && (aray[i][1]==2))
     {
      setcolor(0);
      rectangel(290,370,310,390);
      rectangel(150,280,180,330);
      rectangel(320,370,340,390);
      rectangel(290,210,310,230);
      rectangel(320,210,340,230);
      rectangel(120,370,140,390);
      rectangel(120,210,140,230);
      setcolor(7);
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      rectangel(60,210,80,230);
      rectangel(90,210,110,230);
      rectangel(60,370,80,390);
      rectangel(90,370,110,390);
      rectangel(260,210,280,230);
      rectangel(260,370,280,390);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==2) && (aray[i][1]==0))
     {
       setcolor(0);
       rectangel(150,280,180,330);
       rectangel(320,370,340,390);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
       rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       rectangel(60,210,80,230);
       rectangel(90,210,110,230);
       rectangel(120,210,140,230);
       setcolor(7);
       rectangel(150,200,250,400);
       rectangel(220,280,250,330);
       rectangel(60,370,80,390);
       rectangel(90,370,110,390);
       rectangel(260,210,280,230);
       rectangel(290,210,310,230);
       rectangel(320,210,340,230);
       rectangel(260,370,280,390);
     }
     else if((aray[i][0]==1) && (aray[i][1]==3))
     {
       setcolor(0);
       rectangel(90,370,110,390);
       rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       rectangel(150,280,180,330);
       rectangel(260,210,280,230);
       rectangel(290,210,310,230);
       rectangel(320,210,340,230);
       rectangel(320,370,340,390);
       setcolor(7);
       rectangel(150,200,250,400);
       rectangel(60,210,80,230);
       rectangel(90,210,110,230);
       rectangel(120,210,140,230);
       rectangel(60,370,80,390);
       rectangel(260,370,280,390);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
       rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      }
     else if((aray[i][0]==1) && (aray[i][1]==1))
     {
       setcolor(0);
       rectangel(150,280,180,330);
       rectangel(260,210,280,230);
       rectangel(260,370,280,390);
       rectangel(90,370,110,390);
       rectangel(120,370,140,390);
       rectangel(90,210,110,230);
       rectangel(120,210,140,230);
       setcolor(7);
       rectangel(150,200,250,400);
       rectangel(220,280,250,330);
       rectangel(60,210,80,230);
       rectangel(60,370,80,390);
       rectangel(290,210,310,230);
       rectangel(320,210,340,230);
       rectangel(290,370,310,390);
       rectangel(320,370,340,390);
     }
      else if((aray[i][0]==1) && (aray[i][1]==0))
     {
      setcolor(0);
      rectangel(150,280,180,330);
      rectangel(320,370,340,390);
      rectangel(60,210,80,230);
      rectangel(90,210,110,230);
      rectangel(120,210,140,230);
      rectangel(90,370,110,390);
      rectangel(120,370,140,390);
      setcolor(7);
      rectangel(150,200,250,400);
      rectangel(220,280,250,330);
      rectangel(60,370,80,390);
      rectangel(260,210,280,230);
      rectangel(290,210,310,230);
      rectangel(320,210,340,230);
      rectangel(260,370,280,390);
      rectangel(290,370,310,390);
     }
       else if((aray[i][0]==0) && (aray[i][1]==3))
       {
     setcolor(0);
     rectangel(260,210,280,230);
     rectangel(290,210,310,230);
     rectangel(320,210,340,230);
     rectangel(150,280,180,330);
     rectangel(60,370,80,390);
     rectangel(90,370,110,390);
     rectangel(120,370,140,390);
     setcolor(7);
     rectangel(150,200,250,400);
     rectangel(60,210,80,230);
     rectangel(90,210,110,230);
     rectangel(120,210,140,230);
     rectangel(220,280,250,330);
     rectangel(260,370,280,390);
     rectangel(290,370,310,390);
     rectangel(320,370,340,390);
       }
       else if((aray[i][0]==0) && (aray[i][1]==0))
       {
     setcolor(0);
     rectangel(60,210,80,230);
     rectangel(90,210,110,230);
     rectangel(120,210,140,230);
     rectangel(60,370,80,390);
     rectangel(90,370,110,390);
     rectangel(120,370,140,390);
     rectangel(150,280,180,330);
     setcolor(7);
     rectangel(150,200,250,400);
     rectangel(220,280,250,330);
     rectangel(260,210,280,230);
     rectangel(290,210,310,230);
     rectangel(320,210,340,230);
     rectangel(260,370,280,390);
     rectangel(290,370,310,390);
     rectangel(320,370,340,390);
       }
      }
     getch();
       }
    getch();
}
```

[image]

Comment: _"...but it still shows some error..."_ please include the first few errors as text in your question.  Also read [mcve] as you have included too much code.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile this code as C++? It is clearly C.

Comment: Probably you should look for another code. It looks like it's written for a very old compiler version. iostream.h was used 20  years ago.

Comment: dos.h, conio.h and graphics.h are also almost ancient. As is devC++.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Posting some 700 lines of code to illustrate a handful of syntax errors is excessive.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm a noob :D, i'll try to not act like this anymore

Answer (score 4):

The first error reported by the compiler is : "::main must return an int"

if you change your main function to

```
int main(void) {
 ...
 your code
 ...
 return 0;
}
```

the error should go away.

Second error:
you declared "i" in the for cycle. After the for cycle it is no more available in c++.

this code will not compile:

```
for(int i = 0; i <5;++i) {
   ...
}
for(i = 0; i <5;++i) { // error i variable doesn't exist here
   ...
}
```

this one will compile:

```
for(int i = 0; i <5;++i) {
   ...
}
for(int i = 0; i <5;++i) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: i did what u said. but there is another error. [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] ,  for this lin : ```initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "d:\\tc\\bgi");

Comment: it's not an error, but a warning. The program can probably run with that warning.
The warning is related o the conversion from "d:\\tc\\bgi" which is a constant string to char*.